If $a,b,c$ be the sides of a triangle such that $a+b+c=2$,then prove that $ab+bc+ca+abc<1$
If $a,b,c$ be sides of a triangle such that $a+b+c=2$,
then prove that $$ ab + bc +ca + abc <1$$
My Attempt
$b+c>a\Rightarrow a+b+c>2a\Rightarrow a<1$.
Similarly, $b<1$ and $c<1$
$ ab + bc +ca + abc =abc\left(\frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}+\frac{1}{c}+1\right)$
After this how to proceed

It doesn't work. If the triangle is equilateral, then each side has length $\frac{2}{3}$, and $ab + bc + ca + abc$ is at least $\frac{4}{3}$ from the first three terms alone.

Indeed, one can easily show that $a = b = c = \frac{2}{3}$ is the worst possible case. Given $a + b + c = 2$, we have$$(a + 1)(b + 1)(c + 1) = abc + ab + bc + ac + 3,$$and by AGM inequality, $(a + 1)(b + 1)(c + 1)$, and $abc + ab + bc + ac$, achieve their maximum when $a = b = c$.

A good trick for problems involving the sides of a triangle is that you can reparametrize them in terms of the distances from where the incircle hits the edges to the vertices.  Namely, there are $x,y,z>0$ such that $$a=y+z,b=x+z,c=x+y.$$  We now have the condition that $x+y+z=1$ and we are trying to bound
$$\begin{split}ab+ac+bc+abc &= (1-x)(1-y)+(1-x)(1-z)+(1-y)(1-z)+(1-x)(1-y)(1-z)\\ 
&= 4-3(x+y+z)+2(xy+yz+xz)-xyz \\ 
&= 1+2(xy+yz+xz)-xyz.\end{split}$$
Your original problem is not correct, but this at least gives you something to bound that has a nicer condition.

As pointed out by Aaron and Theo, your problem is not correct. My guess for the right problem is probably to prove $ab+bc+ca-abc> 1$. I will give a proof of that.
Check that this is equivalent to proving
$$(a+b)(b+c)(c+a) - abc > 2$$
which is equivalent to
$$(1+m)(1+n)(1+p) - (1-m)(1-n)(1-p)>2$$
using $a=m+n, b=m+p, c=n+p$ for $m,n,p>0$ such that $m+n+p=1$.
This is equivalent to proving
$$2mnp + 2\sum m > 2 \iff 2mnp > 0$$
which is clearly true.
